# xinput map-to-output extremely slow on debian Elkhart Lake processor

Tags: debian, linux-kernel, intel, xinput

On an intel elkhart lake, currently my `xinput map-to-output` commands take a very long time to execute, let's say 15 seconds whereas it takes less than a second on a normal computer.
Is there a way to make this command execute faster?